# Date constructor returns NaN in IE, but works in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, date

I'm trying to build a little calendar in JavaScript. I have my dates working great in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE the date functions are returning NaN.

Here is the function :

```
function buildWeek(dateText){
    var headerDates='';
    var newDate = new Date(dateText);

    for(var d=0;d<7;d++){
        headerDates += '<th>' + newDate + '</th>';
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+1);
    }                       

    jQuery('div#headerDates').html('<table><tr>'+headerDates+'</tr></table>');
}
```

`dateText` is the Monday of the current week which is actually set in php in the format of 'm, d, Y', e.g. `"02, 01, 2010"`.

Comment: You have some copy-paste errors on your code sample, look at the for statement: `for(var d=0;d';` that will raise a `SyntaxError`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The Date constructor accepts any value. If the primitive [[value]] of the argument is number, then the Date that is created has that value. If primitive [[value]] is String, then the specification only guarantees that the Date constructor and the parse method are capable of parsing the result of Date.prototype.toString and Date.prototype.toUTCString()

A reliable way to set a Date is to construct one and use the `setFullYear` and `setTime` methods.

An example of that appears here:
http://jibbering.com/faq/#parseDate

ECMA-262 r3 does not define any date formats. Passing string values to the Date constructor or Date.parse has implementation-dependent outcome. It is best avoided.

---

*Edit:*
The entry from comp.lang.javascript FAQ is:
An Extended ISO 8601 local date format `YYYY-MM-DD` can be parsed to a `Date` with the following:-

```
/**Parses string formatted as YYYY-MM-DD to a Date object.
 * If the supplied string does not match the format, an 
 * invalid Date (value NaN) is returned.
 * @param {string} dateStringInRange format YYYY-MM-DD, with year in
 * range of 0000-9999, inclusive.
 * @return {Date} Date object representing the string.
 */

  function parseISO8601(dateStringInRange) {
    var isoExp = /^\s*(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)\s*$/,
        date = new Date(NaN), month,
        parts = isoExp.exec(dateStringInRange);

    if(parts) {
      month = +parts[2];
      date.setFullYear(parts[1], month - 1, parts[3]);
      if(month != date.getMonth() + 1) {
        date.setTime(NaN);
      }
    }
    return date;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Garrett. That function you provided in the link is the best far more concise than anything else I've been able to find, and it works with the date format that I use through the other 99% of the app! Much more consistent than what I was using.

Comment: This is, alas, not good, since many structured formats just use W3C date/time formats (ISO-8601 with full specs or so). So while timestamps are better in many ways (simpler, more efficient, work with all browsers), it is often required that standard date/time data is parser from javascript.

I wonder if jQuery or such would have better parsing methods.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, going crazy why chrome works fine parsing dates while ie7 is saying NAN, good thing $.datepicker.parseDate from jquery is able to parse dates

Comment: What if you want the miliseconds as well?

Comment: I've been using a function that was derived from this code in in order to parse an ISO date/time from a string. On rare occasions I will have a seemingly valid value enter into the `if (month != date.getMonth() + 1)` statement, invalidating the date. For example, `2014-06-01T01:09:22.68`. Can you explain the purpose of this `if` statement?

Answer (score 87):

From a mysql datetime/timestamp format:

```
var dateStr="2011-08-03 09:15:11"; //returned from mysql timestamp/datetime field
var a=dateStr.split(" ");
var d=a[0].split("-");
var t=a[1].split(":");
var date = new Date(d[0],(d[1]-1),d[2],t[0],t[1],t[2]);
```

I hope is useful for someone.
Works in IE FF Chrome

Comment: Works with All browsers. Thnx

Comment: `const a = dateStr.split(' ');
                 const d = a[0].split('-');
                 const t = a[1].split(':');
                 currentValue.created_date  = new Date(+d[0], (+d[1] - 1), +d[2], +t[0], +t[1]);` for ES5 or better.

Answer (score 15):

Don't use "new Date()", because it takes the input date string as local time:

```
new Date('11/08/2010').getTime()-new Date('11/07/2010').getTime();  //90000000
new Date('11/07/2010').getTime()-new Date('11/06/2010').getTime();  //86400000
```

we should use "NewDate()", it takes the input as GMT time:

```
function NewDate(str)
         {str=str.split('-');
          var date=new Date();
          date.setUTCFullYear(str[0], str[1]-1, str[2]);
          date.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
          return date;
         }
NewDate('2010-11-07').toGMTString();
NewDate('2010-11-08').toGMTString();
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's another approach that adds a method to the `Date` object

usage: `var d = (new Date()).parseISO8601("1971-12-15");`

```
    /**
     * Parses the ISO 8601 formated date into a date object, ISO 8601 is YYYY-MM-DD
     * 
     * @param {String} date the date as a string eg 1971-12-15
     * @returns {Date} Date object representing the date of the supplied string
     */
    Date.prototype.parseISO8601 = function(date){
        var matches = date.match(/^\s*(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s*$/);

        if(matches){
            this.setFullYear(parseInt(matches[1]));    
            this.setMonth(parseInt(matches[2]) - 1);    
            this.setDate(parseInt(matches[3]));    
        }

        return this;
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a code snippet that fixes that behavior of IE
(v['date'] is a comma separated date-string, e.g. "2010,4,1"):

```
if($.browser.msie){
    $.lst = v['date'].split(',');
    $.tmp = new Date(parseInt($.lst[0]),parseInt($.lst[1])-1,parseInt($.lst[2]));
} else {
    $.tmp = new Date(v['date']);
}
```

The previous approach didn't consider that JS Date month is ZERO based...

Sorry for not explaining too much, I'm at work and just thought this might help.

Answer (score 2):

I always store my date in UTC time.

This is my own function made from the different functions I found in this page.

It takes a STRING as a mysql DATETIME format (example : 2013-06-15 15:21:41). The checking with the regex is optional. You can delete this part to improve performance.

This function return a timestamp.

**The DATETIME is considered as a UTC date**.
Be carefull : If you expect a local datetime, this function is not for you.

```
    function datetimeToTimestamp(datetime)
    {
        var regDatetime = /^[0-9]{4}-(?:[0]?[0-9]{1}|10|11|12)-(?:[012]?[0-9]{1}|30|31)(?: (?:[01]?[0-9]{1}|20|21|22|23)(?::[0-5]?[0-9]{1})?(?::[0-5]?[0-9]{1})?)?$/;
        if(regDatetime.test(datetime) === false)
            throw("Wrong format for the param. `Y-m-d H:i:s` expected.");

        var a=datetime.split(" ");
        var d=a[0].split("-");
        var t=a[1].split(":");

        var date = new Date();
        date.setUTCFullYear(d[0],(d[1]-1),d[2]);
        date.setUTCHours(t[0],t[1],t[2], 0);

        return date.getTime();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Send the date text and format in which you are sending the datetext in the below method. It will parse and return as date and this is independent of browser.

```
function cal_parse_internal(val, format) {
val = val + "";
format = format + "";
var i_val = 0;
var i_format = 0;
var x, y;
var now = new Date(dbSysCurrentDate);
var year = now.getYear();
var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
var date = now.getDate();

while (i_format < format.length) {
    // Get next token from format string
    var c = format.charAt(i_format);
    var token = "";
    while ((format.charAt(i_format) == c) && (i_format < format.length)) {
        token += format.charAt(i_format++);
    }
    // Extract contents of value based on format token
    if (token == "yyyy" || token == "yy" || token == "y") {
        if (token == "yyyy") { x = 4; y = 4; }
        if (token == "yy")   { x = 2; y = 2; }
        if (token == "y")    { x = 2; y = 4; }
        year = _getInt(val, i_val, x, y);
        if (year == null) { return 0; }
        i_val += year.length;
        if (year.length == 2) {
            if (year > 70) {
                year = 1900 + (year - 0);
            } else {
                year = 2000 + (year - 0);
            }
        }
    } else if (token == "MMMM") {
        month = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < MONTHS_LONG.length; i++) {
            var month_name = MONTHS_LONG[i];
            if (val.substring(i_val, i_val + month_name.length) == month_name) {
                month = i + 1;
                i_val += month_name.length;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (month < 1 || month > 12) { return 0; }
    } else if (token == "MMM") {
        month = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < MONTHS_SHORT.length; i++) {
            var month_name = MONTHS_SHORT[i];
            if (val.substring(i_val, i_val + month_name.length) == month_name) {
                month = i + 1;
                i_val += month_name.length;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (month < 1 || month > 12) { return 0; }
    } else if (token == "MM" || token == "M") {     
        month = _getInt(val, i_val, token.length, 2);
        if (month == null || month < 1 || month > 12) { return 0; }
        i_val += month.length;
    } else if (token == "dd" || token == "d") {
        date = _getInt(val, i_val, token.length, 2);
        if (date == null || date < 1 || date > 31) { return 0; }
        i_val += date.length;
    } else {
        if (val.substring(i_val, i_val+token.length) != token) {return 0;}
        else {i_val += token.length;}
    }
}

// If there are any trailing characters left in the value, it doesn't match
if (i_val != val.length) { return 0; }

// Is date valid for month?
if (month == 2) {
    // Check for leap year
    if ((year%4 == 0 && year%100 != 0) || (year%400 == 0)) { // leap year
        if (date > 29) { return false; }
    } else {
        if (date > 28) { return false; }
    }
}
if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
    if (date > 30) { return false; }
}
return new Date(year, month - 1, date);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Valli. I went with garrett's answer below, as the function he linked to was smaller, and worked with the date format I regularly use.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach:

```
var parseDate = function(dateArg) {
    var dateValues = dateArg.split('-');
    var date = new Date(dateValues[0],dateValues[1],dateValues[2]);
    return date.format("m/d/Y");
}
```

replace `('-')` with the delimeter you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The Date constructor in JavaScript needs a string in one of the date formats supported by the parse() method.

Apparently, the format you are specifying isn't supported in IE, so you'll need to either change the PHP code, or parse the string manually in JavaScript.

Comment: That much is pretty obvious, but it would be good to know what supported formats might be...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to parse ISO8601 date string:

```
function parseISO8601(d) {
    var timestamp = d;
    if (typeof (d) !== 'number') {
        timestamp = Date.parse(d);
    }
    return new Date(timestamp);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out using `getDate` feature of `datepicker`.

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd',new Date(pField.datepicker("getDate")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above solution but nothing worked for me.
I did some brainstorming and found this and worked fine in IE11 as well.

```js
value="2020-08-10 05:22:44.0";
var date=new Date(value.replace(" ","T")).$format("d/m/yy h:i:s");
console.log(date);
```

if $format is not working for you use format only.