# How to turn a string into a date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, date

How could I turn this string

```
Sun Apr 25, 2010 3:30pm
```

Into a valid Date in JavaScript (Minimal code is what I'm aiming for here)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try Datejs http://www.datejs.com/
This would not require much coding on your part, but would require including this script in your html.

Comment: Woo! Wish it wouldn't have died, it's incredibly easy to work with in jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

`Date.parse` almost gets you what you want.  It chokes on the `am`/`pm` part, but with some hacking you can get it to work:

```
var str = 'Sun Apr 25, 2010 3:30pm',
    timestamp;

timestamp = Date.parse(str.replace(/[ap]m$/i, ''));

if(str.match(/pm$/i) >= 0) {
    timestamp += 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
}
```

Minicode looks like this:

```
var s = 'Sun Apr 25, 2010 3:30pm';

Date.parse(s.slice(0,-2))+432E5*/pm$/.test(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

The outcome of your approach is not guaranteed by any specification.

ECMAScript Edition 3 is the pertinent one, and does not specify any formats that that Date.parse can parse. Moreover, the specification states that when `Date.parse` is supplied a value that could not be produced by either `Date.prototype.toString` or `Date.prototype.toLocaleString`, the result is implementation-dependent.

> ...the value produced by `Date.parse` is implementation-dependent when given any string value that could not be produced in that implementation by the `toString` or `toUTCString` method.

Do not expect consistent results from `Date.parse` when passing in your own locale-specific date format.

ISO-8601 format can be used and the value can be parsed by your program. See also:
[Date constructor returns NaN in IE, but works in Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182246/javascript-dates-in-ie-nan-firefox-chrome-ok)

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that.  I kinda trusted Firefox blindly on this one.  xD