# Convert date string to date

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

I have a string `Mar 7 2012`.

How do I convert this to a Date object, so I can use `mydate.getDate()`, `mydate.getMonth()`, `mydate.getFullYear()` etc?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn a string into a date in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769901/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Its pretty simple

```
var d =new Date("March 7 2012");
document.write(d.getMonth()); //use it
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `Date.parse` in conjunction with `Date#setTime`. For example:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(Date.parse("Mar 7 2012"));
```

You've pretty good reference docs in mozilla's dev. network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: and you'll notice that this is input is not compliant with the spec, so it's working by chance.