# Highchart doesn't display in IE7/8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, highcharts

I have a problem when I use highchart to display data a on chart. It works fine in FireFox and Chrome but does not display on IE7/8. This my code to display data on chart http://jsfiddle.net/YjpE2/5/ . Please help me resolve my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

IE is not parsing your dates correctly - if you check the value of `newdate` in the loop, it's always `NaN` (Not a Number). Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182246/javascript-dates-in-ie-nan-firefox-chrome-ok) about how to successfully parse dates across all browsers.

The easiest way to get this to work is to change your dates to use `/` as the separator instead of `-`. This gets your example working in IE.