# Javascript new Date object from String, Different results on IE and FF

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to create a new date object from string as follows:

```
var myDate= new Date("1985-01-01T00:00:00.000-06:00");
```

On FireFox, it alerts the following

> Tue Jan 01 1985 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

On IE8, it alerts the following

> NaN

Why IE is acting up this way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript dates in IE, NAN - firefox & chrome ok](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182246/javascript-dates-in-ie-nan-firefox-chrome-ok)

Comment: Because IE8 doesn't support this format. Simple as that.

Comment: Hi balusC, Whats the simplest way of creating a date with String for IE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking to the [documetation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) the right format is the following:

```
  new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond ])
```

So if you run the following code it will be fine in all browsers:

```
 var myDate= new Date(1985, 01, 01 , 00, 06, 00, 0000000000);
 myDate // you get the right date in all browsers IE8/7 included
```

Comment: this will not get right date,cos ie8 count month from '0' not '1', so 'new Date(1985, 01, 01 , 00, 06, 00, 0000000000)' get Feb not Jun, you need to decrease 1 when you past month parameter

Answer (score 2):

Try [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for all your JS Date woes.

Comment: Can you give a code sample of how moment.js can be used to answer the question?

Comment: @JustinStolle var myDate = moment('1985-01-01T00:00:00.000-06:00');

Answer (score 0):

The format is not supported by IE. Maybe you could try using `setUTCHours`:

```
var rawdate = new Date("1985/01/01 00:00:00 GMT");
console.log(rawdate);
  //=> in my timezone: Tue Jan 1 01:00:00 UTC+0100 1985
console.log(rawdate.setUTCHours(-6));
  //=> in my timezone that results in: Mon Dec 31 19:00:00 UTC+0100 1984
```

Or maybe you mean (works in IE, not in other browsers)?

```
var rawdate = new Date("1985/01/01 00:00:00 GMT-6");
  //=> Tue Jan 1 07:00:00 UTC+0100 1985
```