# Parse a Python datetime string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, date, date-parsing

I need to parse a Python-generated datetime string into a Javascript Date object. I went the simplest route:

**In Python:**

```
dstring = str(mydate)
```

example dstring = '2012-05-16 19:20:35.243710-04:00'

**In Javascript (with [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library):**

```
d = new Date(dstring);
```

This gets me a correct date object in Chrome, but an "Invalid Date" error in Firefox and Safari (on Mac).

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript dates in IE, NAN - firefox & chrome ok](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182246/javascript-dates-in-ie-nan-firefox-chrome-ok)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the string into a JS Date. The `Date` constructor is not enough. Maybe you should consider using a library such as datejs:

http://www.datejs.com/

Datejs extends the `Date` object with useful methods such as:

```
Date.parse('Thu, 1 July 2004 22:30:00');
```

Needless to say that date/time formats are customizable.

Comment: as a matter of fact I *am* using datejs already- didn't even realize, I've updated my question. So the library itself isn't working in ffox/safari?..

Comment: But if you are invoking it as you say in your post, you are doing it wrong. You should do it as I show in my answer: `d = Date.parse('...');`

Comment: Sorry Pedro I missed that- doing it now, but getting a null result

Comment: @Yarin, cause your date is in a format that datejs does not recognize. Try keeping only the first 19 chars of your date string (`date_string.slice(0,19)`) and it should work.

Comment: But that loses timezone- there's got to be a way to parse ISO dates

Comment: Actually, I can ignore timezones for this use case, so this takes care of it for me. Thanks Pedro you the man-

Comment: Yeah, I don't think `parseExact`'s syntax supports timezones anyway :/