# How to convert datetime from python to Javascript and HTML output?

Tags: javascript, python, datetime, flask

In a Flask project, I did a function that returns a list of dates picked from the database. I take that result in a javascript function to put in a HTML tag. But I get dates in a JSON format as below:

```
{'0': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 13, 17, 13, 34), '1': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 13, 19, 06, 20)}
```

This is what I get in my HTML page, and I would like to know if there is a way to simplify it in order to get it like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>13/09/2019 17:13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13/09/2019 19:06</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<style>
  table,
  td {
    border: 1px solid #333;
  }
  
  thead,
  tfoot {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
  }
</style>
```

In a way that can fit into a simple table no matter how many dates I get from the database.

I tried with `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`, but it didn't recognize the python `datetime` (Console output: datetime is not defined).

How can I use this JSON information in a JavaScript function?

Thank you.

Comment: is [this what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628169/parse-a-python-datetime-string-in-javascript) ?

Comment: or maybe this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663552/keep-a-datetime-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format-when-using-flasks-jsonify