# count down not working fine in IE

Tags: php, javascript

i m running a count down for the deals page in my project it is working fine in chrome and Firefox but in IE it gives NAN on every box of my code is  as in c the value is; 
the link of my project is  http://blog.merimobiles.com/deals/customer.php
var c = '02 28 2013, 23:59:59';

```
var count=0;
$(document).ready(function ()
{
var c = <?php echo $date ;?>; 
$('#superoffer'+count).epiclock({mode: $.epiclock.modes.countdown, time: new Date(c)});
count++;
});
```

[image]

Comment: check here you may get some useful things : http://www.solvethiserror.com/javascript/javascript-countdown-clock-not-working-in-ie-or-ios-solution-7-238368.asp#Post_235207

Answer (score 1):

You can read this question which will allows you to solve your problem. Please check the accepted answer.

[Date constructor returns NaN in IE, but works in Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182246/javascript-dates-in-ie-nan-firefox-chrome-ok)

> The Date constructor in JavaScript needs a string in one of the date
>   formats supported by the parse() method.

Comment: i have done it by parsing the date thanks

Comment: Since you are new here, accept the answer(tick) which solved your problem. Up-vote(up arrow) the answer(s) which give(s) you information or help(s) you. Down-vote(down arrow) the answer(s) which are fake.