# javascript create Date from string Browser depended

Tags: javascript, datetime

In javascript, I can not do  new Date("10Apr14")   in IE, it will give back invalid Date,  but the same command works fine in chrome.

Anyone knows how to make it work for all browers?

Thanks

Comment: Read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Possible duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182246/javascript-dates-in-ie-nan-firefox-chrome-ok

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using a 2 digit year (see year in [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14)). You should use:

```
new Date('10Apr2014'); // April 10, 2014
```

Or better yet, don't pass a string into the `Date` constructor because that can be error prone and is generally less common. It is much better to use it like this:

```
new Date(2014, 3, 10); // April 10, 2014
```

See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date