# Convert 2014-11-03T00:00:00 to yyyy-mm-dd in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, internet-explorer-8

I have tried to change this date in yyyy-mm-dd using

```
function convert(str) {                
                var date = new Date(str);
                var mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
                var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
                return [date.getFullYear(), mnth, day].join("-");
            }
```

But it's giving me the error Naan in i.e 8. It's working with all other browsers.

Any one can help me in this?

Thanks

Comment: Appears to be a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182246/javascript-dates-in-ie-nan-firefox-chrome-ok

Comment: @Superdrac, it's giving me the error here var date = new Date(str); so i am not able proceed.

Comment: To create a date from one with a T just do `str = str.replace("T"," ")` but no need. Just `return str.split("T")[0]`

Comment: @f01, i have tried but it's not working with that also dude..

Comment: @mplungjan, it's now working

Comment: check [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)

Comment: check http://momentjs.com/

Comment: check [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to go from

```
2014-11-03T00:00:00
```

to

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

you just need

```
function convert(str) {
  return str.split("T")[0];
}
```

To create a date from one with a T and dashes, try

```js
function convert(str) {
  var parts = str.split("T");
  var dParts = parts[0].split("-");
  var tParts = parts[1].split(":");
  return new Date(dParts[0],dParts[1],dParts[2],tParts[0],tParts[1],tParts[2]);
}
var d = convert("2014-11-03T00:00:00");
alert(d);
```