# How to make time string with timezone works in IE11

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer

All:

I wonder how can I build a Date() object from a string like:

```
2016-05-31 07:35:22+02:00
```

In IE 11?

In Firefox and Chrome, I can simply use new Date("2016-05-31 07:35:22+02:00")
but not work in IE11

Any idea?  Thanks

Comment: Did you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182246/date-constructor-returns-nan-in-ie-but-works-in-firefox-and-chrome

Comment: Using the Date constructor or Date.parse for parsing strings is not recommended as parsing is largely implementation dependent and differs across browsers (as you've discovered). Far better to manually parse strings and provide the format to the parser, a library can help but a function for a single format isn't difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a T before the time in the string:

```
new Date('2016-05-31T07:35:22+02:00')
```

That worked in IE for me

Comment: Thanks, save my day! Could you tell me what this time format is called? Is it ISO-time? And why add "T" simply sovles in IE?

Comment: ISO 8601 time format requires a T between date and time.