# Parsing date in javascript issues with IE

Tags: javascript, date, parsing

I'm trying to parse 2016-11-03 09:06:30.087 to a date object in javascript using the new Date() function.

It works fine in firefox however IE will not recognize it as a date.

Any tips?
Thanks

Comment: Every question about parsing dates in JavaScript has been asked and answered here. Please search.

Comment: What code did you use to get this result?

Comment: I am trying to turn 2016-11-03 09:06:30.087 into a date object as it is a string initially

Comment: Please refer the below link for the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182246/date-constructor-returns-nan-in-ie-but-works-in-firefox-and-chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The string given to the date constructor should be an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 formatted date. In your example it isn't. Try the following:

new Date("2012-11-02T19:30:00.000Z");

or using an alternate constructor:

new Date(2012, 11, 2, 19, 30, 0)