# Formatted date from jquery displays NaN in IE

Tags: jquery, datetime, nan

I have the following code on a web page:

```
var date = new Date(row.EventDate.replace('T', ' ')); // 'T' comes from sql server
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var day = date.getDate();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
return '<span>' +
    (month > 9 ? month : '0' + month) +
    '/' +
    (day > 9 ? day : '0' + day) +
    '/' +
    year +
    ' ' +
    (hours > 9 ? hours : '0' + hours) +
    ':' +
    (minutes > 9 ? minutes : '0' + minutes) +
    '</span>';
```

Chome displays as `02/27/2017 13:30` as expected, but IE shows `NaN/NaN/NaN NaN:NaN`

I have read several posts about issues setting a date field having issues like this, but I am setting a text string.

Where am I having the disconnect as to why IE is complaining about something not being a number?

Comment: I'm assuming the format for row.EventDate is YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss?  If so, that is something IE has struggled with.  Look here: http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari/

Comment: @Rick Burns - Yes, its coming as a direct Linq pull from SQL Server

Comment: @RickBurns  amazing link provided by you. Greate

Comment: this is useful with solution:-http://stackoverflow.com/a/2182529/4248328

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date constructor returns NaN in IE, but works in Firefox and Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182246/date-constructor-returns-nan-in-ie-but-works-in-firefox-and-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE has struggeled with this for a while.  The following formats will work in most (all) modern browsers.  Change your `row.EventDate` model output to match one of the following formats and it should work just fine.

Source: http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari/

```js
var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07); // yyyy, mm-1, dd
var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07, 11, 05, 00); // yyyy, mm-1, dd, hh, mm, ss
var d = new Date("02/07/2011"); // "mm/dd/yyyy"
var d = new Date("02/07/2011 11:05:00"); // "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
var d = new Date(1297076700000); // milliseconds
var d = new Date("Mon Feb 07 2011 11:05:00 GMT"); // ""Day Mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss GMT/UTC
```

Comment: The only format that's cross-browser is ISO 8601 format (i.e., "2011-02-07T11:05:00Z")

Comment: OMG! Thanks to Mike's response, I tried removing the ```.replace('T',' ')``` from my code changing the feed to ```new Date()``` from ```2017-01-01 00:00:00``` to ```2017-01-01T00:00:00``` add it works perfect !!!!

Comment: @RickBurns Did you see the version numbers of the browsers on that reference? Things have changed since version 10 of Chrome...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, exactly my point.  This example from version 10 of Chrome still stands today as cross-browser supported date formats.  Not just ISO 8601.

Comment: Hey, if you want to depend on those formats never changing, rock on, but the spec only defines ISO 8601.

Comment: Spoke too soon.  Grrr... Leaving ```T``` in no resolves to Z time instead of locale time.

Comment: @KeithClark, if you specify the timezone offset instead of Z (no offset), or convert to Z time before javascript parsing, it should output as you want.

Comment: @KeithClark, I should say if you use ISO 8601 as mentioned in the comments, the default is Z time, if you specify a format as provided in the answer, it will assume local time.